# Grails inside a <g:each> who creates rows change class of a <tr>

Tags: grails, gsp

I have my grails view, and using a api rest I Receive an array of items,that I put in a table,and I want to make the pair rows  with tr class="alt">
I want for first  for second ,and so on.
I was thinking to do that with a  or creating a tag,but don´t know really if there is something useful that can use for similar cases.
The tr that I want to change In the code is as

```
<table id="customers">
  <tr>
    <th>Foto</th>
    <th>Nombre</th>
    <th>Vendedor</th>
    <th>Precio</th>
    <th>Estado</th>
    <th>Ciudad</th>
  </tr>
   <g:each in="${results}">
**<tr >**
    <td><img src="${it.thumbnail}"></td>

    <td>${it.title}</td>
    <td>${it.nombre_vendedor}</td>
    <td>${it.price}</td>
    <td>${it.condition}</td>
    <td>${it.address.state_name}</td>

  </tr>
    </g:each>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<g:each in="${results}" status="ix">
  <tr class="${ix % 2 ? 'light' : 'dark'}">
    <td>...
  </tr>
</g:each>
```